# Filter/search table doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a page where I can save actors. They are stored in an array.
And after saving these data, I'm creating a table where I'm inserting the data.

I wanted to create a search element where I can filter my data by name. But it didn't work.

Maybe someone of you knows why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `myFunction`

change

`td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`

to

`td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];`

You wanna check the `name`, use `[0]` check the `id`

Comment: Oh I didn't see it! THANK YOU!